# Illegal instruction

Tags: c, intel, intrinsics

I have the following code, which just xors two vectors:

```
void AddXor256(uint8_t *resBuf, uint8_t *buf1, uint8_t *buf2) {

    __m256i res, a, b;

    a = _mm256_lddqu_si256 ((__m256i const *)buf1);
    b = _mm256_lddqu_si256 ((__m256i const *)buf2);
    res = _mm256_xor_si256 (a,b);

    _mm256_storeu_si256 ((__m256i *)resBuf, res); 

}
```

The same code but using 128-bit intrinsics works fine. But when I try to use 256-bit intrinsics I get the following error:

```
Illegal instruction
```

What may be the problem here?

Comment: The larger instrinsics depend upon the model of the CPU your system has. Not all models support the [more advanced/newer] 256 bit instructions. Under Linux, do `cat /proc/cpuinfo` or get a program that can dump out all information from the `cpuid` instruction. Check to be sure that the model has the H/W support (i.e. instructions).

Comment: More specifically integer 256-bit operations require `AVX2` support. The earlier floating-point `AVX1` variant still provides exclusive-or and might work here.

Comment: I thought that when there is a problem using newer instructions, the compiler would tell me about that. But the problem compiles fine. Furthermore, I'm using Intel Core i7 type of processor.

Comment: @Artyom: AVX/AVX2 support depends on the specific Core i7 model, the line has been around for more than half a decade now. As for the compiler it depends on which one you are using and what flags your are passing to it. Generally speaking it is possible and useful to be able to build executables for other processors, whether entirely different architectures or just minor variations.

Comment: Yeah, I guess, I should have mentioned the flags I give to the compiler. I use gcc  and give it flags: -msse -msse2 -msse3 -msse4 -mavx -mavx2 -fopenmp

Comment: @Artyom: That's likely the issue then. Try `-march=native` instead of explicitly asking for additional instruction sets if you would like to limit code generation to what your particular CPU is capable of executing.